# How to chain multiple futures in order

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous

Given that I have the following data:

```
var uniqueIds = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

I want to perform async requests in order based on the input above:

```
List<Future<void>> futures = uniqueIds.map((e) {
  return APIService.shared
      .networkingRequest(input: e)
      .then((value) => update())
      .onError((error, stackTrace) => {
          handleError(error)});
}).toList();
```

Where I want to trigger something like `futures.waitInOrder(...)` with `whenComplete` handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Dart begins running a `Future`'s computation immediately upon the creation of that `Future`, the only practical way to do this is to create each `Future` immediately prior to awaiting their result, rather than mapping all the values to `Future`s up-front.

What that will look like is something like this:

```dart
void foo(List<int> uniqueIds) async {
  for (final uniqueId in uniqueIds) {
    await APIService.shared
        .networkingRequest(input: uniqueId)
        .then((value) => update())
        .onError((error, stackTrace) {
          handleError(error);
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: Those approaches make total sense to me, and after testing them in my code, it seems like my project still tries to execute them in parallel, which makes me think there's something else going on. Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: Ah, that's because a Future begins its computation as soon as it is created. For that reason, actually the only way to do this that I can think of is a for-loop which creates each future immediately before awaiting it, instead of mapping all the values to futures up front. I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: That's incredible, thank you for such an informative answer!